# Display String for a Number in a query result

Tags: mysql

A Query result is just Numbers and it would be easy to read thru and understand if they are String.
How to mark the String equivalent for a number in the query result.

The Mapping for Numbers vs String has to be in the Query.

select num from table; 
Query Result is 9,2,4,7. 
String literals are to be mapped to this numbers. the num range is from {0-9}
0-Prepaid, 1 -postpaid like wise

Comment: CAn you give some example data to understand it better?

Comment: What kind of mapping do you mean

Comment: select num from table; Query Result is 9,2,4,7. String literals  are to be mapped to this numbers. the num range is from {0-9}

Comment: @SriHarish What strings do you need to map to those numbers 9, 2, 4, 7??

Comment: for example 0- postpaid, 1-Prepraid and like wise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expression for this like so:

```
SELECT 
  ...
  CASE 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Postpaid'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'prepaid'
    ...
   END
...
```

You can do this also using a temp table for example:

```
DECLARE @t Table(NumberToReplace INT, replacewith VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 'Postpaid'),
(2, 'Prepaid'),
...
```

Then you can `JOIN` the two tables to replace the  numbers with the corresponding string:

```
SELECT 
  t1.Column1, t1.Column1, t2.replacewith
FROM YourTable t1
LEFT JOIN temp t2 ON t1.NumberToReplace = t2.NumberToReplace
```

I used `LEFT JOIN` to give `NULL` values for the numbers that had no corresponding strings in the other table.

### [Here is a demo in sQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f40f0/1)

Comment: Thanks... I have to go with the CASE expression...I cannot create a table in DB to have the Mappings

Comment: @SriHarish you can create it as a variable instead.

Comment: SELECT 
   CASE 
    WHEN state=0 THEN 'zero'
    WHEN state =1 THEN 'one'
    WHEN state=2 THEN 'two'
    WHEN state=3 THEN 'three'
    WHEN state=4 THEN 'four'
    WHEN state=5 THEN 'five'
   END AS state
FROM table
  CASE did help.... Thanks Again

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT id, IF(my_field REGEXP '[digit]', 'is_string', 'is_numeric') as result
FROM my_Table
```

Check out this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48a6c/1

Comment: select num from table; Query Result is 9,2,4,7. String literals are to be mapped to this numbers. the num range is from {0-9}

Comment: A regular expression is a powerful way of specifying a pattern for a complex search, BUT it is available in MySQL 5.1 or later only, so if user uses older version this will not work.